# Export component using withStyles() and compose() with Redux/Firebase/Material UI

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, material-ui

So I'm trying to put together this app, using firebase and redux for storage, and Material UI as the design.  I've got the firebase and firestore reducers working and all, I just run into an issue when I try to export a component using both firebase and withStyles();

(It works separately, just throws an error when I try to use both.)

Here's what I've tried:

This works, but the withStyles() is not there.

```
export default compose(
  firebaseConnect([{ collection: 'clients' }]),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(Clients);
```

This works, but it's not connected to firebase.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Clients));
```

I've tried combining them, but each one throws an error.

```
export default compose(
  firebaseConnect([{ collection: 'clients' }]),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(withStyles(styles)(Clients));
```

```
export default compose(
  firebaseConnect([{ collection: 'clients' }]),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  withStyles(styles, {
    name: 'Clients',
  }),
)(Clients);
```

The error thrown is `Uncaught Error: Path is a required parameter within definition object`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What if you try making firebase and connect into variables, then compose them? I've done it for redux and apollo in the past. 
`const withFirebase = firebaseConnect([{ collection: 'clients' }]); 
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps); 
export default compose(withFirebase, withConnect)(withStyles(styles)(Clients));`

Comment: @BrandonMitchell Thanks, just tried it, but it still throws the same error... I'm thinking maybe I should just connect to Firebase on a higher-up component, like App, and then pass the firebase data through props. That way, I won't have an overlap between withStyles() and firebaseConnect()

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some messing around, I figured it out. I have to place the firebaseConnect() *inside* of the connect, where the actions would usually go.

```
const withFirebase = firebaseConnect([{ collection: 'clients' }]);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, withFirebase)(withStyles(styles)(Clients));
```